# Visual Studio 2010 with MVC 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I just downloaded and  installed MVC 4 on VS 2010 Professional. I started a new project and here's the list of Errors that i got on my first build-

1.The type or namespace 'Infrastructure'  does not exist in the namespace 'System.data.Entity'(Are you missing an assembly reference?)

2.Namespace 'schema' does not exist in namespace 'System.componentmodel.dataannotations'..
similar is the case with 'dbcontext','dbset','tablettribute','table','databasegeneratedattribute' .....

- Please suggest what references do i need to include for these errors.?
- How can i include the entity framework to my project as it  says that it cannot be found?

This is the first time i am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with VS 2010.

I googled but didnt find the exact solution for this.

Please help!

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have install Entity Framework thats y you got that type of error

you can solve this problem by do this

1. open Vs 2010
2. go to tools
3. select Library Package Manager
4. Go to Manage NUget Packages or Package Manager Console
5. if you use Package Manager Console type this command on console

   Install-Package Entity-Framework
6. if you use Manage NUget Packages
   Download EF5 and install it

Comment: Thanks.I am done with the other errors (except my point No. 2).

Comment: I think i need to upgrade or reinstall Power Shell to overcome this error.